# need help with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I have a class called `CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController` which displays a tableView.
Now, inside this class I wanna create a `UINavigationController` and set the root of the `UINavigationController` this class:

Here is what I did:

```
CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.h

 UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

in the implementation file

```
CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.m

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController *catalog =[[CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController alloc] init];

    loadingView.hidden=YES;
   navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:catalog];

}
```

When I click on the table cell I do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];

    [navigationController release];

}
```

But when I run and click on the tableView nothing happens...not view is showed up!!!Where am I going wrong?

**IMPORTANT**: I don't have a delegate file.Only `CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.h` `CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.m` and `CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.xib`.

EDIT:

```
- (IBAction)showViewCataloguesEtTarifsPDF:(id)sender{
    // Remove view to middleView
    [mainMenuViewController removeViewsToMiddleView];
    // create view controller
    cataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController = [[CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController alloc] init];
    cataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController.mainMenuViewController = mainMenuViewController;

   // hide/show header button
    [mainMenuViewController.headerViewController showMainMenuButton];
    // highlight footer tabbar button
    [mainMenuViewController.footerViewController.footerTabBar setSelectedItem:mainMenuViewController.footerViewController.footerTabBarItemMyAudi];   
     UINavigationController*  navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:cataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController];
      [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: That's completely messed up. Why would you want to create another instance of the view controller you're already in inside the viewDidLoad method?
You create a navigation controller for a view hierarchy. You then push and pop view controllers on/off that one navigation controller.

Comment: I'm sure is completly messed up.Help me to do it right!

Comment: The thing is that when I click the tableView I wanna push into the navigationController a new View.And I have to init that navigationController before....that's  why I did what I did

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read this: http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uinavigationcontroller-tutorial/
Or this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1

Or watch this: http://peepcode.com/products/iphone-view-controllers-part-i

That'll give you the basics and you'll be well equipped to answer your question and fix your code :)

PS: You don't have to explicitly create and set a UINavigationController in your view controller. If the view controller is embedded within a navigation controller, the navigationController property of your view controller instance will automatically find it and return it.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have created a UINavigationController as in the tutorial.Can you help me create it?

Comment: Hey George, if after you've read the docs that I've pointed you still can not solve your problem, I'll gladly help.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing in viewDidLoad is wrong.

Wherever you are showing the CataloguesEtTarifsPDFViewController, you should wrap it in a UINavigationController there and show the UINavigationController instead.

This will make sure the navigationController property of UIViewController will be set.

In your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method you should release the webViewController variable instead of the navigationController property.

Comment: Please look at my edit.I did as you told but it shows only an empty screen.I wonder why?